# NHibernate pattern for logically-linked objects without passing ISession everywhere

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Suppose I have a class named 'Customer' and it makes sense to have a method on the class like:

```
void AddOrder(Item item, int quantity, decimal pricePerUnit)
```

The AddOrder method would conceptually create new records in the database.

From a C# standpoint, there's no problem with the method signature above, but for NHibernate's purposes it needs to have access to the ISession to save the new objects into the database.

What's the appropriate pattern for achieving this without making every method on my persistent classes have an ISession parameter?

Should I descend my persistent classes from a common abstract ancestor that receives the current ISession instance using dependency injection? (i.e. implement a thin wrapper for the ISession that acts as an object factory that handles all create or fetch requests)

Is there a good pattern for this?

PS - I know I don't want to use the Repository pattern.  It is much too free-form for a highly-complicated data model.

---

Clarification:

The data model in question is a double-entry accounting system.  Most developers have zero knowledge about the mechanics of double-entry, nor do they want it.  So, what I would like to do is provide code methods that indicate to a developer *"What can I do with this object?"*, rather than only using properties, which is the normal NHibernate way.

I've used NHibernate now for a fair number of projects, and I keep coming back to the conclusion that I really should put all data interactions for very complex systems behind a highly-structured API and the only people who work on the back-end of that API should be experts on the data/persistence model.  Programmers who just interact with the data would just know how to use the API.  This is not the conclusion I really want to make, since it will add a fair amount of development overhead to some of our systems.  (Of course, this is the path to a service-oriented architecture and just may be a 'given' these days for large projects)

Comment: You're negating many of the benefits that can be had by using an O/RM by forcing all changes to persist to the database immediately. Can you clarify a little more? I'd be a bit concerned with your object model if you believe it's too complicated for NHibernate to handle without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Michael _When_ the ISession.Save() is invoked is not my concern.  I'm more concerned about how developers interacting with the persistence model in their code without needing for them to become experts on the little 'bits and pieces'.  Adding an example above for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Customer` is a persistent class, you would not need to access the session object to add a new `Item` record. Customer needs to have a collection property `Items` mapped as an "has many or many-to-many" association with the cascade mapping option set to "save" or "all".

The `AddItem()` method should simply add an `Item` instance to the `Items` collection of the `Customer` object. Once you commit the NHibernate transaction (usually done in an action filter, http module or some other infrastructure class), NHibernate will save all the records.

If `Customer` is a newly instantiated class, you will have to call the `Save` method of the current `ISession` instance. You would also have to call the `Remove` method to delete a persistent object.

I usually create a very generic simple DAO service to add/remove/get-by-id aggregate roots. Cascading and fetch paths take care of the associated objects. For complex querying you can create query objects that access the `ISession` instance through dependency injection.

Edit: it sounds like you want the objects to persist right away. I would recommend keeping the transactions short rather than referencing  and flushing the session manually . While it is possible to do that later correctly, usually you are negative a lot of ORM data integrity benefits.

Comment: I believe you are correct that the mapping is the only way.